# Flutter: Keep bottomNavigationBar when pushAndRemoveUntil to a page with a bottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this problem. My home page has a bottomNavigationBar with 2 pages A and B.
Pages A and B have buttons that when tapped navigate to other pages which don't have bottom Navigation Bars. Now, when I am in these other pages that don't have bottom navigation bars and would like to  return to my home page, that is the pages with bottom Navigation bars (A & B), using "Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => A()), (Route route) => false),", the bottom Navigation Bar in page A disappears. The same happens when I navigate to page B.
How can I "pushAndRemoveUntil" to either pages (A & B) in my home page without losing the bottom Navigation Bar?

This is how I have implemented the bottom Navigation Bar:

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          A(),
          B(),
        ],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        backgroundColor: appbar_Color,
        currentIndex: pageIndex,
        onTap: onTap,
        activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text("Page A"),
            icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text("Page B"),
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

my onTap function:

```
onTap(int pageIndex) {
    pageController.animateToPage(pageIndex,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.easeInOut);
  }
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi I think the proplem is: Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => A()), (Route route) => false). It navigator to A class not the class contains A & B. You should be navigator to the class contain A & B class.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `Navigator.pop(context)` on other pages as they are just a stack on top of your current Scaffold containing PageView of 2 Pages. Just pop the page out and you will be redirected with the same screen.

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for your answer. I am using `Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil` because when I make changes to pages A and B, for example add an item to a listView in either pages A or B, then call  `Navigator.of(context).pop()`, the page that is popped doesn't refresh to show the new changes. `Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil` however loads the page with the new changes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that you want to use `pushAndRemoveUntil` that push the given route onto the navigator, and then remove all the previous routes until the predicate returns true. It seems that you want to use `pop` (one view back) or `popUntil` (back until finding requested one)

This command will take you directly to the first view in the stack

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
```

This other command will go one view back in the stack

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for your answer. I am using `Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil` because when I make changes to pages A and B, for example add an item to a listView in either pages A or B, then call  `Navigator.of(context).pop()`, the page that is popped doesn't refresh to show the new changes. `Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil` however loads the page with the new changes.